# Create markers from JSON array php mySQL Google Maps v2 android

Tags: android, mysql, json, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to create markers on Google Maps v2 from my mySQL database and it is not working. The map does come up but there are no markers. Can any one tell me what is wrong and what I need to change? I've also tried having the getDouble be getDouble(0) and getDouble(1) but I read somewhere to try 0 and 2. It also has a bunch of imports from multiple tutorials I've tried. I'll remove later.

My Activity

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ReadComments extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "JsOn ErRoR";

    private static final String SERVICE_URL = "my url";

    protected GoogleMap mapB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.get_local);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mapB == null) {
            mapB = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapB))
                    .getMap();
            if (mapB != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    retrieveAndAddCities();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot retrive cities", e);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    protected void retrieveAndAddCities() throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            // Connect to the web service
            URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Read the JSON data into the StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                json.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e);
            throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e);
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        // Must run this on the UI thread since it's a UI operation.
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    createMarkersFromJson(json.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

        List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Marker marker = mapB.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title(jsonObj.getString("business_name"))
                .position(new LatLng(
                        jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                        jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(2)
                 ))
            );
            markers.add(marker);
        }
    }
}
```

my JSON output from my url

```
    [{"business_name":"Wine Bar","latlng":["43.6894658949280400","-116.3533687591552700"],
"business_id":"2","distance":"23.0298400562551"},
{"business_name":"Apple Headquarters","latlng":["37.3324083200000000","-122.0304781500000000"],
"business_id":"3","distance":"23.0298400562551"}]
```

my Logcat (I do not know how to pull the whole log cat but these are the errors)

```
08-21 00:00:27.371: E/JsOn ErRoR(357):  at com..ReadComments.createMarkersFromJson(ReadComments.java:127)
08-21 00:00:27.371: E/JsOn ErRoR(357):  at com..ReadComments$2.run(ReadComments.java:107)
```

Partial Screenshot

[image: Partial Screenshot]

Comment: are the preceding spaces there in the josn there in the string, or is it formatting on so

Comment: That's SO I believe my jSON has no spaces

Comment: ReadComments.java:127 Which one is line 127. and line 107

Comment: createMarkersFromJson(json.toString());  line 107

Comment: jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),line 127

Comment: Are you sure its not jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(2). This looks wrong. should br getDouble(1)

Comment: yah I just tried changing it back to 0 and 1 same error ill post part of the screen

Comment: try sysouting jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng")

Comment: //like this// System.out.print(jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng"));

Comment: I put it under JSONObject             System.out.println(jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0));
            System.out.println(jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1));

Comment: same error then error at line 124 were I put it

Comment: I meant System.out.print(jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng")). What does this show

Comment: 08-21 01:30:12.725: E/JsOn ErRoR(4158):  at com..ReadComments.createMarkersFromJson(ReadComments.java:124)
08-21 01:30:12.725: E/JsOn ErRoR(4158):  at com..ReadComments$2.run(ReadComments.java:107)

Comment: what is the exception body?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `"43.6894658949280400"` is not a double, it's a string. So stop using `getDouble(0)` and use `getString(0)` instead. It will return a string, convert it to double using `Double.valueOf(yourString)`.

Comment: I have it working I'm going to post it later

Comment: Please post your solution, cause I am having the same problem. Also, can you post you PHP or you can send it on my email: aleksanadr.panic85@gmail.com. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've Got the right code here its working perfect.
it has been updated to go to the current location as well because I've been messing with it since the fix.

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class GetLocalBus extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "JsOn ErRoR";

    private static final String SERVICE_URL = "";

    protected GoogleMap mapB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.get_local);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

     // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available   

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapB);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            mapB = fm.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            mapB.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 



             // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                    onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mapB == null) {
            mapB = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapB))
                    .getMap();
            if (mapB != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    retrieveAndAddCities();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot retrive cities", e);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    protected void retrieveAndAddCities() throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            // Connect to the web service
            URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Read the JSON data into the StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                json.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e);
            throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e);
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        // Must run this on the UI thread since it's a UI operation.
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    createMarkersFromJson(json.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        System.out.print(json);
        List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.print(jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng"));
            Marker marker = mapB.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title(jsonObj.getString("business_name"))
                .position(new LatLng(
                        jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                        jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1)))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.graphic_map_icon))
            );
            markers.add(marker);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();     

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        mapB.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        mapB.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Also here is the PHP

```
<?php




    if
    (isset($_GET['lat']) && isset($_GET['lon'])&& isset($_GET['dist'])){



    //make a simple database connection
        $db = new mysqli();



     $lat = $_GET['lat'];

         $lon = $_GET['lon'];

         $dist = $_GET['dist'];




        $search_sql = "SELECT business_id, business_name, CONCAT_WS(\",\",business_lat, business_lon) AS latlng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( " . $lat . " ) ) * cos( radians( " . $lon . " ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( " . $lat . " ) ) ) ) AS distance

                        FROM somewhere HAVING distance < " . $dist . " ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20";






        $search_results = $db->query($search_sql);



        if($search_results->num_rows){



     while ($row = $search_results->fetch_assoc())
{
    $return_data[] = array(
                            'business_name' => $row['business_name'],
                            'latlng'        => explode(',', $row['latlng']),
                            'business_id'   => $row['business_id'],
                            'distance'      => $row['distance']
                            );
}//end while


        }

        else{

            $return_data[] = array();

        }//end if




        }else{


        $return_data[] = array();

    }



    $bd_json = json_encode($return_data);



    $db->close();



    echo $bd_json;





?>
```

xml layout

```
    <fragment android:id="@+id/mapB" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="250.0dip" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/TextView1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/mapB" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Problem is that you are doing HTTP request in MainActivity. That one should go in AsyncTask. Everything else is working just fine :)

Comment: Hello Billy Thank you for your answer, do you still have the complete project of your answer?

Comment: Hello Billy Thanks for your answer, I want to create same project like you do, can I look at your full code?