# Storing Google Maps Android API V2 marker locations in MySQL - TITLE

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps

I know I am running the risk of being blocked but I am already on it a long time. Well, I was storing Google Maps Android API V2 marker locations in MySQL normally and everything is okay with it, the problem is, I wanted to put the title instead of Latitude and Longitude on .title to marker, I have tried use the String, but I am getting just errors. Well, the code is below, if I get the answer of this issue I will share here:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment
        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Creating GoogleMap from SupportMapFragment
        mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation button for the Google Map
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Setting OnClickEvent listener for the GoogleMap
        mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latlng) {
                addMarker(latlng);
                sendToServer(latlng);
            }
        });

        // Starting locations retrieve task
        new RetrieveTask().execute();

    }

    // Adding marker on the GoogleMaps
    private void addMarker(LatLng latlng) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latlng);
        markerOptions.title(latlng.latitude + "," + latlng.longitude);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    // Invoking background thread to store the touched location in Remove MySQL server
    private void sendToServer(LatLng latlng) {
        new SaveTask().execute(latlng);
    }


    // Background thread to save the location in remove MySQL server
    private class SaveTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
            String lat = Double.toString(params[0].latitude);
            String lng = Double.toString(params[0].longitude);
            String strUrl = "http://192.168.0.106/pontos/save.php";                 
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(strUrl);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
                        connection.getOutputStream());

                outputStreamWriter.write("lat=" + lat + "&lng="+lng);               
                outputStreamWriter.flush();
                outputStreamWriter.close();

                InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";

                while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
                iStream.close();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

    // Background task to retrieve locations from remote mysql server
    private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String strUrl = "http://192.168.0.106/pontos/retrieve.php";             
            URL url = null;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                url = new URL(strUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();              
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));         
                String line = "";               
                while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();
                iStream.close();                            

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new ParserTask().execute(result);
        }

    }

    // Background thread to parse the JSON data retrieved from MySQL server
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<HashMap<String, String>>>{
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... params) {
            MarkerJSONParser markerParser = new MarkerJSONParser();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            List<HashMap<String, String>> markersList = markerParser.parse(json);
            return markersList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            for(int i=0; i<result.size();i++){
                HashMap<String, String> marker = result.get(i);
                LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lat")), Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lng")) );
                addMarker(latlng);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MarkerJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list */
    public List<HashMap<String,String>> parse(JSONObject jObject){      

        JSONArray jMarkers = null;
        try {           
            /** Retrieves all the elements in the 'markers' array */
            jMarkers = jObject.getJSONArray("markers");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /** Invoking getMarkers with the array of json object
         * where each json object represent a marker
         */
        return getMarkers(jMarkers);
    }


    private List<HashMap<String, String>> getMarkers(JSONArray jMarkers){
        int markersCount = jMarkers.length();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> markersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> marker = null;  

        /** Taking each marker, parses and adds to list object */
        for(int i=0; i<markersCount;i++){
            try {
                /** Call getMarker with marker JSON object to parse the marker */
                marker = getMarker((JSONObject)jMarkers.get(i));
                markersList.add(marker);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return markersList;
    }

    /** Parsing the Marker JSON object */
    private HashMap<String, String> getMarker(JSONObject jMarker){

        HashMap<String, String> marker = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String lat = "-NA-";
        String lng ="-NA-";


        try {
            // Extracting latitude, if available
            if(!jMarker.isNull("lat")){
                lat = jMarker.getString("lat");
            }

            // Extracting longitude, if available
            if(!jMarker.isNull("lng")){
                lng = jMarker.getString("lng");
            }                   

            marker.put("lat", lat);
            marker.put("lng", lng);         

        } catch (JSONException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return marker;
    }
}
```

Well, I know how to configure out the PHP files, but if you think is necessary to see it, here's the code: [Download - PHP Files](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/?wpdmdl=9378)

Thank you ever so much!

Comment: For `Create markers on Google Maps v2 from my mySQL database`, you can refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350189/create-markers-from-json-array-php-mysql-google-maps-v2-android).

Comment: Could explain me better the part of the php? The only thing I am trying to do is use title for the marks and the HashMap accepts just two types for the latitude and longitude, what should I do for titles to the markers? Thanks for your help!